# Replace method in static class

Tags: typescript, class, ecmascript-6

I am looking for a specific kind of functionality.

Below I have a `StringHandler` class and a `StringOrNullHandler` class. Both have static methods.

```
export class StringHandler {
    static getString (s): string {
        if (s === 'red') throw new Error;
        return s; 
    }
    static getStrings (s: string[]) : string[] {
        return s.map(StringHandler.getString);
    }
}

export class StringOrNullHandler {
    static getString (s): string | null {
        if (s === 'red') return null;
        return s; 
    }
}
```

I am interested in replacing the `StringOrNullHandler.getString` method and changing the way that the `StringOrNullHandler.getStrings` method would perform.

```
StringHandler.getStrings(['red']) // throws
StringOrNullHandler.getStrings(['red']) // return [null]
```

I can do something like this where they are not using `static` methods, and I can extend the class.

```
export class _StringHandler {
    getString (s): string {
        if (s === 'red') throw new Error;
        return s; 
    }
    getStrings (s: string[]) : string[] {
        return s.map(this.getString);
    }
}

export const StringHandler = new _StringHandler();

export class _StringOrNullHandler extends _StringHandler{
    getString (s): string | null {
        if (s === 'red') return null;
        return s; 
    }
}

export const StringOrNullHandler = new _StringHandler();

StringHandler.getStrings(['red']) // throws
StringOrNullHandler.getStrings(['red']) // return [null]
```

But Now I have a different problem the `StringOrNullHandler.getStrings` method still thinks that the return type can only be a string and not nullable.

Is there a more composable way to gain this functionality?

Comment: Your snippets seem to be wrong. In the first one `StringOrNullHandler.getStrings` isn't defined at all. In your second snippet the `_StringOrNullHandler.getString` method is erroneously marked as static.

Comment: Furthermore your `StringOrNullHandler` object is instantiated the same as the `StringHandler`. Is it just a typo or your actual code and the reason it does not work?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to move the functionality to a common generic abstract base class where the `getString` method is abstract and returns a type parameter `T`. Then `_StringHandler` and `_StringOrNullHandler` can implement their versions that return `string` or `string | null` respectively.

```
abstract class _StringHandlerBase<T> {
    abstract getString(s: string) : T;
    getStrings (s: string[]) : T[] {
        return s.map(this.getString);
    }
}
export class _StringHandler extends _StringHandlerBase<string> {
    getString (s: string): string {
        if (s === 'red') throw new Error;
        return s; 
    }
}

export const StringHandler = new _StringHandler();

export class _StringOrNullHandler extends _StringHandlerBase<string | null>{
    getString (s: string): string | null {
        if (s === 'red') return null;
        return s; 
    }
}

export const StringOrNullHandler = new _StringOrNullHandler();

StringHandler.getStrings(['red']) // typed as string[]
StringOrNullHandler.getStrings(['red']) // return (string | null)[]
```